# C: Stop background process when it reads input

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a shell program for a class right now and I have an issue with background jobs.

Below is a snippet where I assign the child process to the foreground group or the background group.

When I run `sleep 20 &`, it would run in the background, which is good. However, when I do `cat &`, it would just finish immediately. But in the actually bash shell, it would stop the program.

From what I read, when the background program gets stdin, it would receive SIGTTIN and it will stop running. I wonder why it is not working here.

```
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
    printf("Error forking the process\n");
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    // child code
    // execute command
    execvp(args[0], args);
  } else {
    //parent code
    if (!isBackground) {
      // set to the foreground process group
      if (fgLeader == -1) {
        fgLeader = pid;
      }
      setpgid(pid, fgLeader);

      // block the shell until the foreground process finish
      int wstatus;
      waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);

    } else {
      printf("Running process: %d in the background.\n", pid);
      // set to the background process group
      if (bgLeader == -1) {
        bgLeader = pid;
      }
      setpgid(pid, bgLeader);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please put the missing parts of your code in your question to make it a [mcve].

Comment: You called `exec` while the child is still in the foreground process group.

Comment: move the assignment group code inside the child, right before exec and it worked! Thanks! @WilliamPursell